# add values to json arrays

Tags: json, jq

I have some JSON objects that I need to add a value to if it doesn't already exist.

Each object will be the following except the contact_group inside each array (1-5) will vary:

```
{
"contact_groups": {
    "1": [
      "/contact_group/78"
    ],
    "2": [
      "/contact_group/79"
    ],
    "3": [],
    "4": [],
    "5": []
  }
}
```

I would like to add `"/contact_group/109"` to each array if it doesn't already exist, so the above would become:

```
{
"contact_groups": {
    "1": [
      "/contact_group/78",
      "/contact_group/109"
    ],
    "2": [
      "/contact_group/79",
      "/contact_group/109"
    ],
    "3": [
      "/contact_group/109"
    ],
    "4": [
      "/contact_group/109"
    ],
    "5": [
      "/contact_group/109"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure jq can do this but I'm really inexperienced with it so I don't know where to begin.  Does anyone know how/if this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `with_entries()` function on the parent element to convert the sub elements into a pair keyed by `key` and `value` and add the string to `value` array, if it doesn't have it already

```
jq '.contact_groups |= ( with_entries( if ( .value | index("/contact_group/109") | not ) then .value += [ "/contact_group/109" ] else . end ) )'
```

The `with_entries(..)` builtin is a shorthand for doing `to_entries | map | from_entries`. The `index("/contact_group/109") | not` part ensures to add the entry if the string is *not* already present in the `.value` array.

<sup>[See demo on jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/tBKr0H-7XB)</sup>